# Pass updated value to parent in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello people at Stack Overflow!

I have two components, `NewArticle` and `HoveringMenu`.

In `NewArticle` I have a JSON object which looks like this:

```
const initialValue = Value.fromJSON({
  document: {
    nodes: [
      {
        object: 'block',
        type: 'paragraph',
        nodes: [
          {
            object: 'text',
            leaves: [
              {
                text: 'Tell your story...'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

I have to have it in order for a package that I use to work.

In `NewArticle`'s state I have that `initialValue` as my content which I later pass down to my `HoveringMenu` component:

`<HoveringMenu value={this.state.values.content} />`

Just to clarify, `content` is equal to the `initialValue`.

And inside of the `HoveringMenu` component I have a bunch of functions which enables me to edit the text and change style of it etc. But when I submit the new edited text to my server it wont get updated since my `submit` function is in the other component, `NewArticle`. Which just takes the content:

```
content: JSON.stringify(this.state.values.content.toJSON())
```

from it's own state, meaning the none edited text (Tell your story...) from the `initialValue` variable.

So I just wonder how I can pass the new written text to the `NewArticle` component. Or if I should try to solve this problem some other way.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the state in `NewArticle` and passing the props to the `HoveringMenu` is a good idea but updating it in the child is not.

You should call the setState of the parent component (`NewArticle`) from the "bunch of functions" in the child component (`HoveringMenu`).

Basically, if you are having the state in the parent and passing it as a props to the child then make sure you change the state in the parent only. Otherwise, you would have to sync the state in the parent and child.
(Also, you can make use of component lifecycles methods in the child component to know if the props changed or not like **componentWillReceiveProps**)

So, you can pass a function to the child which updates the parent state, something like this:

```
<HoveringMenu value={this.state.values} updateValue={this.updateValue}  />
```

and your updateValue function would be doing

```
updateValue: function(values) {
    this.setState({
        values: values
    })
};
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! I understood it as I should have the `updateValue` function in my `NewArticle` component and pass down it's state to the `HoveringMenu`. But I'm uncertain what to do with the `updateValue` that I'm passing down. Would it be ok if I send the two files so you could take a look at them? Thanks!

Comment: Yes sure. 
You have to call the updateValue prop from the child component.